# apache2 tomcat6 virtual hosting

Tags: server, 9.10, apache2, tomcat

I've apache2 and tomcat6 running on port 80 on ubuntu server 9.10. I've a registered domain name and I'll access the jsp index page navigating to http://abc.mydomain.com.
The page is under tomcat_home/webapps/myapp and the below are tomcat virtual hosting in server.xml file:

```
<Host name="abc.mydomain.com" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true">
<Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger"
directory="logs" prefix="virtual_log1." suffix=".log" timestamp="true"/>
<Context path="" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapps" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

Recently a new domain has been bought(xyz.mydomain.com) and I'm asked to do the virtual hosting so that the new domain name directly points the page "admin.jsp" which is located under 'tomcat_home/webapps/myapps/WE-INF/js/'. How could I do this?

If I type http://abc.mydomain.com/admin I'll get the page what I wanted. I should access the page just by typing http://xyz.mydomain.com.

Comment: If you find you don't get an answer here, you may want to ask this question on http://serverfault.com/, or see if it has been asked there before.

Answer (score 1):

In web.xml in the welcome file List. Example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Just add another line that refers to admin.jsp.

Thanks
Chris